# Set instance variable name based on argument passed in Python class

Tags: python, class

I want to be able to set the instance variable name in a Python class based on an argument in `__init__`. Is this possible? Below is what I've tried but that doesn't work.

```
class my_class:
  def __init__(self, var_name):
    self['var' + var_name] = var_name
```

Comment: Don't do that.  It's just not good practice to create names on the fly.  Instead, use a dictionary.  That's exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? What's the context? When you say "variable name", that makes me think [*identifier*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), but your code uses a [*subscription*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), and it sort of sounds like you're actually talking about an [*attribute*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references). Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I create variable variables?](/q/1373164/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below.

(*Question*: why do you want to do that?)

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, var_name):
    setattr(self,var_name,var_name)

c = MyClass('jack')
print(c.jack)
```

output

```
jack
```